# Dockerfile CMD Command not using variable

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In a dockerfile copy worked with the variable work_dir

```
ARG WORK_DIR=/home/myuser/work
COPY ./code $WORK_DIR/code
```

but the command does seem not to use it

```
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "${WORK_DIR}/start.sh" ]
```

is answered with

```
sh: 1: /start.sh: not found
```

omitting the workdir. How to properly add a path variable to the command ?